# Wordpress specific post that leads to specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a "Blog" page on my website. The thing is I have a looped list of posts on my "Blog" page. Every post has a button 'Read more'. What I need is when you click on that button 'Read more' it should open "Blog inner page" which has a custom styled template (that you may set in your admin panel) where you can read more information about the current post. So technicaly it should like, when you create a new post-page it should create new post with short information on "Blog" page or vise-versa.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to write some loop function that loops the posts on the page, and after clicking on a specific post, redirects to the page with detailed information. That is my question, what is the function and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the Read More button should be called like this :
Needs to be add in functions.php file

```
// Changing excerpt more
   function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More &raquo;' . '</a>';
   }
   add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

The above code will automatically adds the Read more link to that post with the complete post content.

Also, you can try this with your current setup  : echo get_permalink();